# TIniFile.ReadSection stops at first empty line

Tags: delphi

Say I have an ini file containing:

```
[Section_1]
one=1
two=2

four=4
five=5
```

then, when later use `TIniFile.ReadSection('Section_1', MyStringList)`, `MyStringList` will not contain the empty line that is present in the `.ini` file.

How can I overcome this and have `MyStringList` contain all the lines, *including* the empty one?

I need to populate a `TMemo` from the ini section and I must rely on the fact that each line must be loaded into the `TMemo`, from the ini section, even blank lines.

Comment: You should be loading the file into the memo in that case.

Comment: INI standards to not regard empty lines. If this is a required format, then it is purely custom, and thus shouldn't rely on `TIniFile`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blank lines are ignored, both in `TIniFile` and `TMemIniFile`.  If you need to load blank lines, you will have to parse the file yourself, such as with a `TStringList`:

```
MyStringList.LoadFromFile('file.ini');
i := MyStringList.IndexOf('[Section_1]');
if i >= 0 then
begin
  for j := i+1 to MyStringList.Count-1 do
  begin
    s := Trim(MyStringList[j]);
    if (s <> '') and (s[1] = '[') and (s[Length(s)] = ']') then
      Break;
    // add s to Memo as needed...
  end;
end;
```